# Is iPad pro resolution support mandatory for AppStore Upload?

Tags: ios, objective-c

if I am uploading an app to store and it doesn't support ipad pro in layout. i.e Layout may seems stretched with small icons or images. Will Apple approve my application? what i can still do is I can add

Comment: No apple doesn't approve your app try to fix it

Comment: if you are making an ipad app for sure apple will reject... if you are making for iphone, it will approve...

Comment: Okay thanks Guys. but if it is the case then how can i handle my UI on ipad pro. like small icons and small views etc as we don't have ipad pro support in asset manager. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using size classes? What kind of application are you building?

Comment: I am developing a universal application but due to lack of stability of xcode, size classes and ease of use. I using different storyboards for both ipad and iphone.

Answer (score 1):

The iPad pro is @2x device, and you should support it like any other iPad. I would recommend checking out apple's human interface guidelines:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html